# Question regarding natural numbers in Tao’s Analysis 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

This doubt might be a mistake on my part, but its confused me for a while now so I decided to ask here.

In Terrence Tao’s “Analysis 1”, at the beginning of the chapter about Natural Numbers (where he uses the Peano Axioms to define them) he asks the reader to forget everything about the standard rules of algebra and to start from scratch.

However, when he starts to define incrementation as counting forward, or an increase in number, I hit a block. How can I think of increase in numbers without the order axioms? The increment operation itself makes no sense to me without a previously established notion of what is greater and lesser, i.e., some form of the order axioms, and to set the order axioms we need the addition axioms, and this seems to oppose the notion that the Peano Axioms are the most fundamental axioms needed to define natural numbers.

Maybe I’m just interpreting what Tao meant by “counting forward” wrongly, in which case, I would appreciate if someone gave me some pointers about the right way to think about this.

Comment: You inductively define the naturals - with peano axiom - by the successor operation. Thus addition by $1$ is *defined* as the application of the successor operation; succession is part of the package of axioms

Comment: We have to start somewhere... The author says (page 16): "we will use two fundamental concepts: the *zero* number 0, and the increment operation." Thus, we have to rely on two undefined concepts: an initial "point" and a single-step move that at each point produce the "next one". That's all.

Comment: "How can I think of increase in numbers without the order axioms?" You've been told how to: "forget everything about the standard rules of algebra and to start from scratch". _Do not_ recall that $Sn>n$. Don't even recall the symbol $>$.

Comment: What might help you is to visualize some sets on which you can define something very similar to the increment operator. For instance: you have the n corners of an n-gon and the increment operator is just moving to the nearest neighbor counterclockwise. Or you have an infinite checker board and succesion is just moving one step up, like a pawn would do or something else. Now these things do not look very much like the natural numbers so at somepoint maybe some other axiom or unexpected consequence of the axioms might kick in that rules out these examples, but it is useful to see where exactly

Comment: If you would really have forgotten about numbers and then start reading about sets with successor operators you might as well have pictured one of the above, so it is useful to check at what point your picture has to be amended to become more like the natural numbers. But there is also something else. Supposed that after reading and understanding all axioms we are left with a picture that is consistent with it then (for the story to make sense) it should be possible to take the next step: (see next comment)

Comment: Next step:  wake up and remember again what numbers were. Then: for each suddenly re-remembered characteristics of numbers  find out to which aspect of the weird-picture-you-constructed-in-your-head-when-trying-to-visualize-the-thing-described-by-the-axioms each characteristic of the natural numbers corresponds. This is an interesting exercise (at least to someone who *really* forgot and then re-remembered) and what Tao is doing when 'already' referring to the succession operator as increasing the number is essentially a 'spoiler' about what you will experience when doing that exercise.